# Can Ansible hash files using lookup similar to how it can hash strings (e.g., {{ 'test1' | hash('sha1') }})?

Tags: ansible

**Can Ansible hash files using lookup similar to how it can hash strings (e.g., {{ 'test1' | hash('sha1') }})?**

See, https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#hashing-and-encrypting-strings-and-passwords

Linux command line (WORKS)

```
sha1sum /etc/default/grub
```

returns hash: f2de8d3dfe08c34615145f212e5a32facf575cb3

Ansible stat module (WORKS)

```
- name: checksum | /etc/default/grub (stat)
  delegate_to: localhost
  stat:
    path: "/etc/default/grub"
    checksum_algorithm: sha1
  register: local_grub_orig_sha1
```

returns hash: f2de8d3dfe08c34615145f212e5a32facf575cb3

Ansible lookup with hash filter (FAILS)

```
- name: checksum | /etc/default/grub (lookup)
  delegate_to: localhost
  set_fact:
    local_grub_sha1: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/default/grub') | hash('sha1') }}"
```

returns hash: 834f3f662f6a19cf273d87a00d4af2645ab18dcd

NOTE: This implementation is limited to localhost. See [@Vladimir Botka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6482561/vladimir-botka)'s answer below for a general solution using stat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [*stat*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#ansible-builtin-stat-retrieve-file-or-file-system-status). Test it, for example

```yaml
    - stat:
        path: /etc/passwd
        checksum_algorithm: sha256
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stat.checksum

    - command: sha256sum /etc/passwd
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

You should see the same results from the *command* and *stat*.

Comment: Right, as also shown under [Save part of a result in Ansible using register, set_fact, or filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71348638/6771046).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by using `lookup('template', ...)` rather than `lookup('file', ...)`. However, it is not clear to me what is causing the difference in behavior.

```
- name: set_fact checksum | /etc/default/grub
  set_fact:
    grub_template_result_sha1: "{{ lookup('template', '/etc/default/grub') | hash('sha1') }}"
```

returns hash: f2de8d3dfe08c34615145f212e5a32facf575cb3

Comment: I"d put a dime on a trailing new line that one or the other lookup add/trim.

Comment: Please keep in mind that [Lookups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_lookups.html) "_like all templating, ... execute and are evaluated on the Ansible Control Machine_" only. Therefore it is non distributable solution, it will not work for Remote Nodes.